# cannot find cert for ngrok websocket secure

Tags: ssl, ngrok

When I connect my embedded board's WSS client to wss://echo.websocket.org, i can use the cert i find using firefox's security tab, the "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" cert. I am able to authenticate on my board and echo information.

but if i use my server's https://*.ngrok.io/ in my WSS client, with the cert i find on the ngrok.io website, my board tells me that it fails to verify peer certificate.

But I have no problem connecting websocket.org's echo client to my https://*.ngrok.io/ server. what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to use openssl to extract the cert.